# Map is not a function and type error when reading dummy data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to display a dummy data from a URL in my component. I use TS and Next.js for this. Unfortunately I get a type of error I don't know why

typings.d.ts:

```
export type Themen = {
 id: number;
 title: string;
 description: string;
 price: number;
 discountPercentage: number;
 rating: number;
 stock: number;
 brand: string;
 category: string;
 thumbnail: string;
 images: string[];
};
```

page.tsx:

```
 const loadThemen = async () => {
 const loadTheme = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/products");
 const data: Themen[] = await loadTheme.json();

 //LOGs DATA
 console.log(data);
 return data;
};


export default async function DetailThemepage() {
const fake = await loadThemen();

{fake?.map((thema) => (
     <div>{thema.title}</div>
))}
```

> TypeError: fake.map is not a function

Comment: If `fake.map` is not a function then `fake` is not an array.  At runtime, when you debug, what is the observed value of `fake` when the error occurs?  What value was expected?

Comment: Moreover, you actually have `console.log(data)`. What does it log? Is it an array?

Comment: Oh okay my fault. The result is not actually an array, it looks like this: {"products":[{"id":1,"title":"iPhone 9","description":"An apple mobile which is nothing like apple","price":....}]. So how can i handle in TS an Object(products) with Object Array?

Comment: @Captai-N: Do you just want to `return data.products;` instead then?  I mean, "how you'd handle it" is by matching your type definitions to the data you're expecting.  So if you want the function to return an array of data then you'd return an array of data.  Or if you want the function to return the whole object then you'd update the expected return type to match that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the data provided by the `API URL` you're requesting, I notice that you are, as I suspected, getting an object ; not an array.

To resolve your error, you have 2 options:

- Return the `products` property in the `loadThemen` function
- Access the `products` property of `fake` before calling `map`

Here are both solutions:

```
// Returning the products property of data
const loadThemen = async () => {
     const loadTheme = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/products")
     const data = await loadTheme.json()
     return data.products
}
const fake = await loadThemen()
{fake.map((thema) => <div key={thema.id}>{thema.title}</div>)}

// OR

// accessing the products property before running map
const loadThemen = async () => {
     const loadTheme = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/products")
     const data = await loadTheme.json()
     return data
}
const fake = await loadThemen()
{fake.products.map((thema) => <div key={thema.id}>{thema.title}</div>)}
```

So there you have it, this will work perfectly. well. Although, id add a type notation on each `thema` in the map - i.e. `(thema:Themen)`